# R ggplot2 graph with scienfitic notation AND set number of digits after decimal

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get axis values to be in scientific notation while having a set number of digits after the decimal.  So 1.22E10 or 5.00E1 if I need two places after the decimal.

The accuracy argument in scales::number_format does exactly what I want with decimal places.  One of the arguments in base::format is scientific, which puts the number in scientific notation when set to TRUE.  scales::number_format says it can pass values for base::foramt, but using accuracy=2 and scientific=TRUE results in an error.

Is there a way to get these two to play nicely together? Or is there another approach that will always have the desired number of places after the decimal?

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

head(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(labels=number_format(accuracy=0.1, scientific=TRUE))
```

Error:

Error in format.default(x_scaled[idx], big.mark = big.mark, decimal.mark = decimal.mark,  :
formal argument "scientific" matched by multiple actual arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the labels directly with `sprintf`:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~ sprintf(fmt = "%0.02e", .))
```

[image: ggplot with 2-decimal scientific notation]

- the `e` in the `fmt=` format means *"Double precision value, in “*e*xponential” decimal notation of the form ‘[-]m.ddde[+-]xx’"*; use `E` instead if you prefer the upper-case E instead, as in *‘[-]m.dddE[+-]xx’* (ref: [`?sprintf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html))
- `0.02` means 0-padded 2 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

I think you just omitted to write this as a function

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

head(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, accuracy=1, scientific = TRUE))  ## Include formating in a function
```

Comment: Not quite, `scale::number_format` (and its replacement, `scales::label_format`) returns a labeller function, so the issue is not the use of a custom function. (Also, I don't know how to _force_ `format(.)` to show two digits to the right of the decimal mark, the OP requested `5.00E1` or similar.)